# How to shuffle a list in Haskell using random selection

Tags: list, haskell, random, functional-programming, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a list of any a using random numbers. The reason I ask this here is because I have already made a function and I can't figure out why exactly it isn't working.

```
pick :: [a] -> IO a
pick xs = do
    n <- randomRIO (0, length xs - 1)
    return $ xs !! n

shuffle :: [a] -> [IO a]
shuffle ls = do
    x <- pick ls
    let y = remove x ls
    (return x) : shuffle y

-- Remove an element from a list (Only first appearance)
remove :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
remove _ []     = []
remove r (x:xs) = if x == r then xs else x : remove r xs
```

The error I get:

```
num.hs:31:10: error:
    * Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
      Expected type: [a]
        Actual type: IO a
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- pick ls
      In the expression:
        do x <- pick ls
           let y = remove x ls
           (return x) : shuffle y
      In an equation for `shuffle':
          shuffle ls
            = do x <- pick ls
                 let y = ...
                 (return x) : shuffle y
   |
31 |     x <- pick ls
   |          ^^^^^^^
```

What doesn't make sense to me is that it says it received a type [a] instead of IO a for pick, but ls is defined as [a]?

If there is something fundamentally wrong with this that I just don't understand, is there another way to shuffle a list in Haskell that is this simple? Preferably without any imports.

Comment: I think the type of your function should be `[a] -> IO [a]`, not `[a] -> [IO a]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried that and I got two new errors - Too big to post here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that the type signature for `shuffle` implies that its do-block has type `[IO a]`.  This means that the monad for this do-block isn't `IO` as you intend, but rather the monad instance for lists `[]`, as that's the "outermost" type constructor here.  The expression `pick ls` is therefore required, by the do-block, to have type `[t]` for some type `t`, but the type signature for `pick` implies that `pick ls` has type `IO a` for some type `a`.  GHC is complaining that it expected `pick ls` to have a list type `[a]` (because of the type of the do-block) but its actual type was `IO a` (because of the type signature of `pick`).

I believe the conceptual mistake you've made is that you're thinking of `IO` as a kind of modifier on a type that makes it IO-friendly.  So, if `IO a` is an `a` that can be generated using an effectful IO computation, then it must be true that `[IO a]` is a list of `a`s each of which can be generated using an effectful IO computation.  But this is wrong!

Instead, you should think of `IO a` as an IO **action** (like a recipe) that, when executed, can produce an `a`.  If you want a list of such `a`s, you don't want a list of actions/recipes, each of which produces a single `a` (i.e., you don't want `[IO a]`).  Instead, you want a single action/recipe that produces a list of `a`s, so you want an `IO [a]`.

So, `shuffle` should have type signature:

```
shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
```

Making this change will result in another error for the last expression:

```
(return x) : shuffle y
```

The issue here comes from the same conceptual mistake:  you're taking a (trivial) action/recipe for generating `x` and trying to create a list of actions/recipes (though now `shuffle y` isn't a list anymore, so there's a type mismatch).  Instead, you want to replace this with:

```
xs <- shuffle y  -- use `shuffle y :: IO [a]` action to get `xs :: [a]`
return (x:xs)    -- make an action to return the whole list (type `IO [a]`)
```

You'll also find you need to add an `Eq a` constraint to shuffle because it's required to invoke `remove`; also, this will hang unless you properly handle the empty list case.  The final version of `shuffle` would be:

```
shuffle :: (Eq a) => [a] -> IO [a]
shuffle [] = return []
shuffle ls = do
    x <- pick ls
    let y = remove x ls
    xs <- shuffle y
    return (x:xs)
```

and that should work:

```
> shuffle [1..10]
[6,8,7,2,5,10,1,9,4,3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably are looking for a function like:

```
shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
shuffle [] = return []
shuffle ls = do
    x <- pick ls
    fmap (x:) (shuffle (remove x ls))
```

You thus first pick an element from `ls` and then you recurse on the list of the list. Then we can return a list `(x:xs)`.

The above can made more elegant. I leave this as an exercise. It is for example usually not a good idea to calculate the `length` of a list each iteration, since that makes the algorithm *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. Furthermore you might want to rewrite `pick` as a function that returns the item *and* the list after removal.

Comment: Going along this route to get sub-quadratic performance leads to use of sparse ranges like [here](https://github.com/the9000/haskell-99-problems/blob/master/p22.hs) + [here](https://github.com/the9000/haskell-99-problems/blob/master/SparseRange.hs), which is admittedly log-linear in worst case. IDK if a strictly linear solution is possible e.g. by using [arrays](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/arrays.html) that at least allow constant time random access.

Comment: @9000: yes using random acces data structures can result in a linear solution. Furthermore since "linear congruent generators" have some problematic patterns when you plot consequence pairs, it is better to generate a random number between `0` and `n!`.

Comment: @9000 Yes, linear is possible. [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is the go-to standard way.